# Mint a new position Uniswap V3

Tags: web3js, blockchain, uniswap

```
  'mint',
        [
          [
            EthereumAddress.fromHex(linkAddress), //weth
            EthereumAddress.fromHex(daiAddress), //chainlink
            BigInt.from(500),
            BigInt.from(-13000),
            BigInt.from(-10000),
            BigInt.from(5 * pow(10, 18)),
            BigInt.from(5 * pow(10, 18)),
            BigInt.zero,
            BigInt.zero,
            EthereumAddress.fromHex(curAccount),
            BigInt.from(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch / 1000 + 3000)
          ]
        ],
```

I have a mint call like this. But it reverted everytime i call? Where did i go wrong?

Comment: Check that have you approved both tokens for sufficient amounts, and that the wallet has enough of them.

Comment: I've already done it. Approving both and check allowance with erc20 smart contract

Comment: I think it because the pair already exsisted

Comment: it will work the same way whether the pair exists or not

Comment: Do you think it failed because of the upper and lower tick? I don't know how to calculate it so i take the values from an exsisted pair

Comment: Did you find the issue ? I am having the same issue while trying to call function mint(MintParams calldata params)